# caffe error while loading shared libraries libcaffe.so

Tags: c++, caffe

I tried to install caffe and run mnist example, but get the following error:

```
/build/tools/caffe: error while loading shared libraries: libcaffe-nv.so.0.16:
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched for solution and tried export LD_LIBRABRY_PATH but couldn't fix it:

[image result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgVNF.jpg)

p/s: I use caffe of nvidia fork, root caffe also got the same error. 
Anyone can help?

Update: 
[library location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo9hR.jpg)

Comment: Is there `libcaffe-nv.so.0.16` in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (/home/kien/nvidia-caffe/caffe/build/lib)

Comment: @hgminh yes, there is. I updated the location on question for your clarification.

Comment: red filename with black background means broken [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). You should check if you built libcaffe correctly. Never use this so cannot help you there.

Comment: that's very kind of you!